# Как сделать поиск file_get_contents?

Tags: php

Есть функция:

`file_get_contents`

Есть файл: **123.php**

Этот файл интерпретирует определённую фразу (может быть сугубо длинное число, может слово, а может слово вперемешку с числом).

Как сделать так, чтобы функция file_get_contents вызывала **123.php** и искала в нём значение и чтобы выдавалось "найдено", "не найдено"?

Comment: [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pos = strpos(file_get_contents('123.php'),"текст для поиска");
if ($pos === true) {
echo "найдено";
} else {
echo "не найдено";
}
```